# REGEX: Match text with the same special character inside

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple documents that I need to match some codes that we have inside:
The codes have this structure: CRL-LLL-LLL-LLL-LLL-DDDDDD | Example: CRL-SYW-CON-LKA-TMP-800001

There're mainly correct cases, however, there some cases with this situation: CRL-SYW-CON-LKA-TMP-XXXXXX (Because they don't know the number)

Please look at this:
https://gyazo.com/c950b3f687929d19fc7b2cf63cc9721c

Just testing in Sublime text, I came up with something using this: .*-\d{6} but it's take more parts that I don't need:

https://gyazo.com/e410a9267199f567b9d146ce9c3f1839

And idea could be something like this:

- Read and find all strings starting with CRL
- Stop until the next space
- Return the string which contains at least 2 "-"

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you show us what you did so far with Python?

Comment: What you describe is done easily with regex ,try to read a little in regex documentation and you will succeed.

Comment: `\bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{3}){4}-(?:\d{6}|X{6})\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
re.findall(r'\bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{3}){4}-(?:\d{6}|X{6})\b', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldTpdf/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `CRL` - a `CRL` string
- `(?:-[A-Z]{3}){4}`  - four repetitions of `-` and 3 uppercase letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:\d{6}|X{6})` - six digits or six `X` chars
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: This is so good! Is it a way to create a range?? Something like this works for me but looks ugly: \bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{3}){4}-(?:\d{6}|\d{5}|X{6}|X{5}|X{4}|X{3})\b.

Comment: @jjsgana Yes, `(?:\d{5,6}|X{3,6})`. `{5,6}` matches five to six times, and `{3,6}` matches three to six occurrences. These are [*limiting quantifiers*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). Also, there is a nice thing about testing regexps at regex101.com: if you click *Code Generator* link on the left, you will see some [code you may leverage](https://regex101.com/r/ldTpdf/1/codegen?language=python) .

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey Wiktor, I found this situation: https://gyazo.com/676663d300eedae8b4abbf450be574bd .  Is there an easy way to grab those as well in the regex code you gave me?

Comment: @jjsgana There are codes with 4 letter chunks in between hyphens. So, the logic is *3 or 4 letters*, with an optional line break before the 6 digit number or `X`s, right? So, use `[A-Z]{3,4}`: `r'\bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{3,4}){4}-\r?\n(?:\d{6}|X{6})\b'`. You need to read the whole file in the memory for that to work.

Comment: Almost, Is "So, the logic is 3 or 4 letters, with an optional line break before the last chunk of letters": CRL-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX [JUMP LINE] 80000

Comment: I'm trying to implement it but there's no way (definetely I need learn a bit more of Regex). I have this : \bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{1,6}){4}-(?:\d{1,10}|X{1,10})\b. Is working perfectly well except for this elements: https://gyazo.com/05c7d18b10e537318daf2021a7e6e37c. Any idea? Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/ldTpdf/2 Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @jjsgana Use `\bCRL(?:-[A-Z]{1,6}){4}-(?:\r?\n)?(?:\d{1,10}|X{1,10})\b`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldTpdf/3).

Comment: Wow, it works fantastic Wiktor. Thank you for your help. You're a machine on regex mate. It would have taken weeks to learn how to do that. I'll learn a bit more of regex during my free time. Your help its's an awesome incentive to keep learning.

Comment: @jjsgana I described my regex background in [this article](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/my-regex-road-so-far), how I learnt regex. I plan to add more general regex articles in the future there.